# How can I delete all records from a table?

Tags: linq

I've been searching for an answer on how to delete ALL records from a table using LINQ method syntax but all answers do it based on an attribute.

I want to delete every single record from the databse.

The table looks like so:

```
public class Inventory
    {
        public int InventoryId { get; set; }
        public string InventoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm not looking to delete records based on a specific name or id.

I want to delete ALL recods.

LINQ method syntax isn't a must, bt I do prefer it since it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all data from DB table I recommend to use SQL:

```
Trancate Table <tableName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not meant to change the source. There are no LINQ methods to delete or update any element from your input.

The only method to change you input, is to select the (identifiers of the )data that you want to delete in some collection, and then delete the items one by one in a foreach. It might be that your interface with the source collection already has a DeleteRange, in that case you don't have to do the foreach.

Alas you didn't mention what your table was: Is it a `System.Data.DataTable`? Or maybe an Entity Framework `DbSet<...>`? Any other commonly used class that represents a Table?

If you table class is a `System.Data.DataTable`, or implements `ICollection`, it should have a method `Clear`.

If your tabls is an entity framework `DbSet<...>`, then it depends on your Provider (the database management system that you use) whether you can use `Clear'. Usually you need to do the following:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    List<...> itemsToDelete = dbContext.MyTable.Where(...).ToList();
    dbContext.MyTable.RemoveRange(itemsToDelete);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It was a DbSet. I'm not too familiar with databases so that's why I didn't disclose it.
Also I did manage to find another good way to delete all my records from the table , or rather the whole table. What do you think.

`using (DungeonContext context = new DungeonContext())
            {
                context.Inventories.RemoveRange(context.Inventories);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }`

Comment: wasn't this what I wrote in the end? I only did it in two steps, to clearly show what happens